# The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, msbuild

The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Problem occurred when i restarted visual studio application.Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you check if the file or directory actually exists at the mentioned location ?

Comment: I checked it. Windows cant find the specified folder..

Comment: but there exist file on this location "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\ VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"

Comment: Thanks ankit your comment guide me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what actually happend...."VisualStudio" forlder is renamed to " VisualStudio" .. I solved this problem by creating new folder named "ViusalStuido" and copied files from " VisualStuido" to this.